# filter only not empty arrays dataframe spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can i filter only not empty arrays

```
import  org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType

  val arrayFields = secondDF.schema.filter(st => st.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType])
  val names = arrayFields.map(_.name)
```

Or is this code

```
val DF1=DF.select(col("key"),explode(col("objectiveAttachment")).as("collection")).select(col("collection.*"),col("key"))

|-- objectiveAttachment: array (nullable = true) 
 | |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I get this error

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: ArrayBuffer(collection);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the function *size*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

secondDF.filter(size($"objectiveAttachment") > 0)
```

Comment: I get error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: ArrayBuffer(collection);

Comment: When you use explode, you do not have an array anymore. Try just this code:
DF.select(col("key"),explode(col("objectiveAttachment")))

Comment: val df= DF.select(col("ins"),explode(col("objectiveAttachment")).printSchema  Incomplete expression

Comment: you are missing a parenthesis )

Comment: looks like an extra parenthesis to me

Comment: you are right @user3685285. Just fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with size() function from org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val df1=df.select(col("key"),explode(col("objectiveAttachment")).as("collection")).select(col("collection.*"),col("ins"))
.filter(size($"objectiveAttachment")>0)
```

Comment: I get this error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(collection)`;

Comment: My answer was to the filter question, where you can use size() function. Arrays can't be flattened with star operator, you have to use explode() function.

Comment: Always i get error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: ArrayBuffer(collection);

Comment: I mentioned that above. use explode() not star. star operator is only for struct, you are trying to use if for array.